# jQuery returns same value on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey what I'm trying to achieve is to set my progress bar on button click that when I click button my progress bar width adds to 8%. It's working when I click the button first time. But when I click the button second time it doesn't change and stays the same at 8%. How can I solve this problem?

This is what I return on button click:

```
$('.progress-bar').css('width', function(index, value){
    return "+=8%";
});
```

Comment: You need to make use of value as `return (~value + 8) + "%"` `~value` will give you the `value` in integer and you add `8` to it and turn it into a percentage by finally concatenating it with `"%"`

Comment: You are returning a string not a js variable. Must use it like this: return (value + 8) + "%" to add the 8 value to returned value and concatenate the %

Comment: Works fine for me as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zyt8cr0u/